# UIPickerView won't select the first row unless I select a different row first?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uipickerview

It seems that I cannot select the very first row in the UIPickerView when I first load it. I want the textfield to update immediately when I load the picker view. It only updates when I select something else, and then go back to the first row.

```
var platformData = ["XBOX", "PS4", "PC"]
var picker = UIPickerView()

@IBOutlet var platformSelected: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    platformSelected.inputView = picker

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneAction))
    toolbar.items = [doneButton]
    platformSelected.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return platformData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    platformSelected.text = platformData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return platformData[row]
}
```

Comment: The `didSelectRow` means that you change a row. So it's not called once you've present picker view. If you want to assign the first row dy default, just call `platformSelected.text = platformData[0]` one picker open

Comment: You can use this to select the first row upon load: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614382-selectrow

Comment: When you are showing up your picker, select the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Improve your code.

```
platformSelected.delegate = self

......

// MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
extension YourUIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
      // TODO: - Specify index what you need. After editing it changed and you should get selected index using its position in platformData Array
      let index = 0
      picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am relatively new to programming. Is there any chance you could present this code within the code I posted so I can understand where things need to go better? Thank you!

Comment: Setup delegate in viewDidLoad function

Comment: Add extension of your view controller at the current view controller file